# How to pass parameters to the use function inside the middleware when consuming the middleware in Nest js

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs

How can i pass parameters from here

```
export class NotificationModule implements NestModule{
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes(
        {path: 'notification/create', method: RequestMethod.POST},
```

And How can I use passed parameters in here

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(private readonly studentService: StudentService) {
    }

    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
       ????????
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since middlewares are injectables, you could pass the options as any other provider like [this one](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/blob/ad7cd398280ade41aef58c3c7a642641b434aa24/packages/webhooks/src/webhooks.middleware.ts#L37) in which the options are passed in the module [here](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/blob/ad7cd398280ade41aef58c3c7a642641b434aa24/packages/webhooks/src/webhooks.module.ts#L28-L29)

or use [`create-nestjs-middleware-module`](https://github.com/iamolegga/create-nestjs-middleware-module) to turn middlewares into modules

or make a mixin that will return the middleware. Thus, you will pass the options like `consumer.apply(CreateAuthMiddleware(opts))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use mixin pattern here, so solution migth look like

module

```
export class NotificationModule implements NestModule{
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddlewareCreator({ value: true })).forRoutes(
        {path: 'notification/create', method: RequestMethod.POST},
```

and mixin

```
import { Injectable, mixin, NestMiddleware, Type } from '@nestjs/common';
...
export function AuthMiddlewareCreator(options: AuthMiddlewareOptions): Type<NestMiddleware> {

    @Injectable()
    class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
      constructor(private readonly studentService: StudentService) {
      }

      async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        // you can use options here, for example
        const { value } = options;
       ...
     }
  }
  return mixin(AuthMiddleware);
}
```