# How can we pass different parameters to Nest js middleware for different routes?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Like i have to pass a parameters conditions for specific routes of module. This params should be handled in middleware level.

1. One Controller should behave according to some conditions like {x:true,y:false,z:true}
2. Second controller should behave according to some conditions like {x:false,y:false,z:true}

I have tried [How to pass parameters to the use function inside the middleware when consuming the middleware in Nest js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251958/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-use-function-inside-the-middleware-when-consuming)

This will allow only one time parameters but not for each routes.

Comment: have you tried interceptor (https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an interceptor.

This link will really help you understand what and how to use interceptor.

https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

Have fun coding...